# Can I hack org-mode to not visually modify links in headers?

Tags: org-mode

Sometimes I put links in the header title of an org document. Org mode automatically re-colors and underlines the links. I would like my links that appear in section titles to appear unaltered. Is this possible?

For example I'd like the first header of the following document to look like the header section.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: This is probably a bizarre question. I'm motivated by the fact that I use org documents and htmlize to maintain my personal webpage. I want htmlize to render these links to keep the section formatting to make my webpage look cleaner. Right now I have a perl script to edit the files after the html has been generated but I'd prefer to do this on the emacs side.

Comment: Did you look for export filters? http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/filter-markup.html

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm I'm not sure how those would address my issue. These seem useful for exporting org documents but I want to alter the look of the org documents themselves.

Comment: I'm sorry, misunderstood your question...

Comment: I think you just want to change the font lock of those elements. I'm on a phone now, so can't answer comprehensively, but check out the source to darcula-theme, it has commands to find the font-lock you need and customisation examples.

Comment: @fommil Itook a look at the darcula-theme but didn't find much help.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak the `org-link` face to remove the `underline` and other properties using `custom-theme-set-faces`. Here's one way to do it manually.

```
(custom-theme-set-faces
  'whatEverIsYourCurrentTheme
  `(org-link ((,class (:underline nil :foreground ,type ))))))
```

`underline` has been changed from `t` to `nil`. Depending on the theme you are using, you may have other tweaks to tune as well. Look in the theme's customization variables.

Comment: This would change the links globally, correct? I want only the links that appear in header titles to blend in with the rest of the header text.

Comment: That depends on your theme. Look in the customization variables for your theme to change only what you need, all links or just the header links, or radio links, etc.

Comment: You can see the name of the face at point by using `M-x describe-char`.